# Powershell script to get the certificates that are not in use

Tags: powershell

I need some help with the powershell script to get the certificates that are no longer in use in AWS.

$Result = Get-ACMCertificatelist |Get-ACMCertificateDetail
I don't know how to sort after that.

Thanks in advance for your help and time,

Comment: A certificate has an expiry date. In an aggressive scenario you would check the expirydate and confirm that the certificate is indeed expired and then delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I haven't tested this. I don't use AWS. I wrote this solely from AWS documentation for [Get-ACMCertificatelist](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-ACMCertificateList.html) and [Get-ACMCertificateDetail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-ACMCertificateDetail.html).

```
$invalid_certificates = @()
$certificates = Get-ACMCertificatelist

foreach ($certificate in $certificates) {
    $certificate_detail = Get-ACMCertificateDetail -CertificateArn $certificate.CertificateArn

    if ( $certificate_detail.InUseBy.Count -eq 0 ) {
         $invalid_certificates += $certificate
    }
}

## List of invalid certificates
Write-Output $invalid_certificates
```

I don't know what qualifies a certificate as "no longer in use". I'm assuming whatever qualifies that can be found in the certificate properties. You can dial-in what I have here to meet your criteria.

Comment: Inuseby is the one which determines the cert is in use or not. See the following. the cert is not in use.
CertificateArn          : arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:
CreatedAt               : 4/25/2018 1:08:03 PM
DomainName              : 
DomainValidationOptions : 
ExtendedKeyUsages       : 
ImportedAt              : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
InUseBy                 : {}
IssuedAt                : 4/25/2018 2:49:04 PM
Issuer                  : Amazon
KeyAlgorithm            : RSA-2048
KeyUsages               : 
NotAfter                : 5/25/2019 12:00:00 PM
NotBefore               : 4/25/2018 12

Comment: Updated based on your comment, but taking a step back, you see how you can use whatever criteria you'd like here. Just update the if-block.

Comment: Thanks Lord Adam for your help and time. It is working now.